# autocompletion in command line/search

Tags: search, autocompletion

There is some way to "extend" autocomplete functionality (like that one supplied by [SuperTab plugin](http:///github.com/ervandew/supertab)) to be used in **command line mode** so I would autocomplete when searching a text with `/` command?

Explanation:

When editing a text, in INSERT mode, I use now superTab plugin, so hitting TAB, a menu appear with possible completions items.

I'm looking for a similar feature when searching or editing in command mode (`:command`) and/or in serach mode (`/searchedtext`), with autocompletion, retrieving from file text words (ore previous commands!).

E.g. if I have the word `validate_first` and `validate_firstname` inside the file, I would like to have an autocompletion menu when hitting `/validate`, with items:

- `validate_first`
- `validate_firstname`

[image]

Comment: Could you add an example of what you currently do?  And what you would like it to do?

Comment: question updated; more clear now? :)

Comment: perhaps the [searchComplete](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=474) plugin is what you are looking for?

Comment: It seems to me not working. What's he supposed to do searchCompleted? I do not see any behavior change when using `Tab` or  `/`. Nothing happens
BTW I'm using vim v.8.0

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> from cmdline or open cmdline by prefixing your command with `q` (e.g., `q/`) to open the cmdline window, which is a buffer for entering Ex commands. From here, you should be able to use your completion mappings.

`:help cmdline-window`

You could map a command to open the window when you try to do completion in cmdline:

```
cmap <Tab> <C-f>a<Tab>
```

I'm intentionally using `cmap` instead of `cnoremap` to allow `<Tab>` to invoke your completion plugin.

If you use `<Tab>`, you should also change 'wildchar' so you can still access the incredibly useful `wildmenu`. See `:help wildmenu`

---

If you want completion but your current system doesn't support cmdline-window (or you don't don't want to use it), you can use vim's has built-in vim completion: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> for vim completion and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> for ins-completion. You can differentiate `/` from `:` cmdline with `getcmdtype()`:

```
cnoremap <expr> <Tab> getcmdtype() == ':' ? '<C-f>A<C-x><C-v>' : '<C-f>A<C-n>'
```

Comment: Upvoted, thanks. See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/euaocz/autocompletion_in_command_linesearch_modes/  I'm now fine with `cnoremap <Tab> <C-F>A<C-N>`

Comment: @GiorgioRobino: If that works for you, then you might want to try my vim completion/ins-completion edit for better completion on vim commands.

Comment: I'm happy with simple `cmap <Tab> <C-n>` :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not provide an **autocompletion** solution, but a way of filling your history with terms and then cycling through the terms:

Previous commands can be retrieved with the `:his[tory]` command

Previous searches can be retrieved with the `:his[tory] /` command

If you have `incsearch` enabled, you can search for (e.g.) `/valid` which will take you to the first match (perhaps `validate_firstname`).  Pressing `CTRL-L` will add one character from after the current match to the command line. This is not the same as autocomplete with <kbd>TAB</kbd> but it does *complete* the search term.

You can then use `:his /` to find and repeat previous searches.

Once you have `/validate_firstname` and `/validate` in the search history, you can type `/val` followed by the <Up> and <Down> cursor keys to cycle through the search history.

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself to my old question, sharing a solution **partially satisfying** to myself (just to reciprocate people answers):

1. **searches autocompletion**

   I use plugin:

   Plug 'vim-scripts/CmdlineComplete'

   quoting from: https://github.com/vim-scripts/CmdlineComplete :

> When editing the command-line ( `:` `/` etc.),
>
> press `Ctrl-P` or `Ctrl-N` to complete the word before the cursor, using keywords in the current
>   file.
>
> E.g: you want to search for *elephant* in the buffer, just type
>   `/ele` and press `Ctrl-P`. So long as *elephant* is in the buffer, you
>   will get *ele* completed into *elephant*.

---

2. Command line commands history (not a real autocompletion)

   I just use `Up-Arrow` and `Down-Arrow` to retrieve recent commands history

Answer (score 1):

This plugin serves the same purpose (though old one and no development):
https://github.com/vim-scripts/sherlock.vim

Plugin-less way is invoking "q:" key map for opening command line window and can leverage all the completion shortcuts (/) just like any other normal window. This window is pre-populated with command line history

And the shortcut to enter search window "q/". This window is populated with search history

Comment: Thanks Naga, Sherlock plugin is nice but a bit cumbersome because it requires three steps: 1: <TAB> 2: select an item from the popup menu 3: <ENTER>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin-less solution that I personally use and think works very well:

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
cnoremap <expr> <Tab>   getcmdtype() =~ '[\/?]' ? "<C-f>A<C-n>" : "<C-z>"
```

It makes `<Tab>` trigger `Ctrl-f`, enter `INSERT` mode, and starts vim's builtin completion if in search mode. Otherwise, it triggers completion like usual.

This does not prevent `Ctrl-z` from working in normal mode.

`wildcharm` is a bit weird but it allows wildmenu tab completion in mappings/macros : https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildcharm%27

Comment: `wildcharm` is specifically for use in mappings/macros.